# Extjs 4.1b3 - update panel coordinates after resize

Tags: extjs, extjs4

If I re-size the panel to the **TOP** or to the **LEFT**, its **x** and **y** coordinates keeps resetting to initial value. I would like it to behave naturally and update its coordinates: for example, when resizing to the left, the x should decrease proportionally.

What is wrong with this code please?

***version: 4.1-beta3***

**Please try it in this jsFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/astronaute/rgGwr/

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});

Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
        layout: 'absolute',
        items: [
            {
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'panel',
            draggable: true,
            resizable: true,
            x: 100,
            y: 100,
            width: 100,
            height: 100}]
    });
});
```

Comment: I cross posted on their forums: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?185724-Panel-resize-doesn-t-update-coordinates-normal Lets hope someone answer it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can it be a bug of beta-version? Does it work as expected in 4.0.7?